# How would I change an item in a combobox?

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to let users manipulate the data that I have put into a combo box. The thing is I can't figure out a way to apply the change to the data inside the combo box. Any clues as to how to achieve this?

To add some context all the data in my combo box are strings which have the format  "SomeName|#" . The number at the end is modified by the user to whatever he/she desires.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to change the text in the selected combobox item?

```
   comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] = "SomeName|#";
```

As for changing data, if the above is not what you want, than try this:

```
// Get the selected the data from the combobox 
MyData data = comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] as MyData;
// Perform your operations
data.myData = "NewData";
// Add the modified data back
comboBox.Items[comboBox.SelectedIndex] = data;
```

If bound to a list:

```
  // When adding new Data
    MyData newData = new MyData("Data1");
    comboBox1.Items.Add(newData);
    myDataList.Add(newData);

    // When modifying selected data
    MyData data = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] as MyData;
    data.myData = "NewData";
    comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] = myDataList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex] = data;
```

In case you are wondering what MyData is:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string myData;

    public MyData(string p)
    {
        myData = p;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return myData;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Ok, if you are binding to a data source you need to unbind it first, lets assume the data source is myDataList:

```
        // Get the selected data
        MyData data = myDataList[comboBox.SelectedIndex] as MyData;
        // Unbind
        comboBox.DataSource = null;

        // When adding new Data
        MyData newData = new MyData("NewData" + myDataList.Count());
        myDataList.Add(newData);

        // When modifying selected data
        data.myData = "ModifiedData";

        // Rebind
        comboBox.DataSource = myDataList;
```

Comment: I tried using your first option but I got a the error "Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set"

Comment: Do you have a datasource attached to the combobox by any chance?

Comment: I do. Im gonna guess that means I change the data source instead of the combo box.

Comment: Guess I need to figure out how to do that. I don't know a simple way of going about it. The best I can think of is using a do loop to compare if string in my combo box is the same in data source and then change that string and update the combo box to the now changed data source.  That seems kinda stupid though. Also I worry that this will also change which string the user is looking at in the combo box when I update the data source.

Comment: Ok, check after edit, if you are binding to a data source, you can either get the data source, or just the selected data like in my example and unbind the data source, modify the data, rebind the source.